# How to create a file shortcut on Ubuntu using Python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, shortcut

As a better definition, how to write the following function in Python ?

```
def create_shortcut(source, dest):
    create a shortcut of file 'source' and put it in 'dest'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "shortcut" you mean symlink, it's just

```
import os

os.symlink(source,dest)
```